# Function to replace values of elements of matrix with 0 unless the value is -1

Tags: matrix, replacement

How can I write a function that replaces all the elements of a matrix with zero unless the value is -1?

Comment: Have you already tried `-KroneckerDelta[mat, -1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the data of @Syed:

```
ReplaceAt[x_ /; x != -1 :> 0, {All, All}] @ amat
```

{{0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}}

If, for example, we wanted to restrict the replacement to the first 2 rows:

```
ReplaceAt[x_ /; x != -1 :> 0, {1 ;; 2, All}] @ amat
```

{{0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, -1, -3, 0, 1,
1, -2}, {0, 0, 1, -2, 1, -1, -2}}

`ReplaceAt` came with V 13.1

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward solution, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Using Syed's input example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
amat = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {4, 7}];
```

### 1.

You can use [`Unitize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize.html) as follows:

```
bmat = Unitize[amat + 1] - 1;

MatrixForm @ bmat
```

[image]

### 2.

An alternative way to use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
cmat = amat /. {-1 -> -1, _?NumericQ -> 0}

MatrixForm @ cmat
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

We can squish the upper and lower bounds of `Clip` together at -1 to get the desired output:

```
SeedRandom[1];
(amat = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {4, 7}]);


cmat = Clip[amat, {-1, -1}, {0, 0}];


MatrixForm /@ {amat, cmat}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

As an example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
(amat = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {4, 7}]) // MatrixForm

MatrixForm /@ {amat, amat /. {a_ /; a != -1 -> 0}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplacePart` with `Position`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
amat = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {4, 7}];
amat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ReplacePart[#, Position[#, x_ /; x != -1] -> 0] &@amat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One approach I always fall back on is to create a function that does the basic task:

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{-1, x == -1}, {0, x =!= -1}}];
```

Then the function can be mapped over the desired list:

```
Map[g, amat, {2}]
```

Which gives the same answers as the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
SparseArray[Position[amat,-1]-> -1, Dimensions@amat]//Normal

(* {
    {0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,-1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,-1,0}
   } *)
```

To replace all elements not equal to -1 with a value other than zero (10, for example)

```
SparseArray[Position[amat,-1]->-1,Dimensions@amat,10]//Normal

(* {
    {10,10,-1,10,10,10,10},
    {10,10,-1,10,10,10,10},
    {10,-1,10,10,10,10,10},
    {10,10,10,10,10,-1,10}
   } *)
```